# Highlighting duplicate data in rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a query and I cant figure out why it's not correct.

I have two lists of data and I want to highlight the matching data in the separate lists.

Below is the query I have constructed

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$J$2:$J$75,0)),"",B1)
```

Comment: What does "it's not correct" mean? Please include sample input with desired output and actual output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that uses conditional formatting.

1. Highlight the range that you want to be matched to another range.
2. In the menu, go to **Format >> Conditional Formatting...**
3. In the *Conditional Format Rules* overlay, select **Format cells if... >> Custom formula is**.
4. Enter `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$6,0))),True,False)`, where `A2` is the first cell in the range and `$D$2:$D$6` is the list that we are matching to. The image below illustrates.

[image]